# Do Until Recordset.Eof is not working as expected (ASP Classic)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have an Active Server Page, which displays Booking of the current Day.

With that Code i get the Informations from the DataBase:

```
Do Until Recordset.Eof



      rsRaum.open "select raum_id, KOPPELBESTUHLUNG_ID from RESERVIERUNGRAUM where buchung_id = " & Recordset("buchung_id"), Connection
            raum_id = rsRaum("raum_id")
            KOPPELBESTUHLUNG_ID = rsRaum("KOPPELBESTUHLUNG_ID")
      rsRaum.close


      rsRaum.open  "SELECT NAME, FIRMA FROM TEILNEHMER WHERE BUCHUNG_ID =" & Recordset("buchung_id") & "and STATUS = 2 and DAILYPLAN = 1" , Connection
             if not rsRaum.EOF then
                    TeilnehmerNameExtern = rsRaum("NAME")
                    TeilnehmerFirmaExtern = rsRaum("FIRMA")
             end if
      rsRaum.close




      ' hole Raum Details
      rsRaum.open "select bezeichnung from Raum where ID = " & raum_id, Connection

          raumname = rsRaum("bezeichnung")

      rsRaum.close



    Recordset.MoveNext
    Loop
```

So Far it works fine. My Only Problem is that part:

```
rsRaum.open  "SELECT NAME, FIRMA FROM TEILNEHMER WHERE BUCHUNG_ID =" & Recordset("buchung_id") & "and STATUS = 2 and DAILYPLAN = 1" , Connection
             if not rsRaum.EOF then
                    TeilnehmerNameExtern = rsRaum("NAME")
                    TeilnehmerFirmaExtern = rsRaum("FIRMA")
             end if
      rsRaum.close
```

My Problem:

I have a Booking, to that Booking i assign three Participants (TEILNEHMER). But if i try to display the Participants, the ASP is only displaying one of that three Participants, which i assigned to that booking.

What should i do to get all the Participants which are assigned to that booking? Do i have to loop also through that part of Code? I have tried but nothing worked.

Can Someone help me?

EDIT :

```
rsRaum.open  "SELECT NAME, FIRMA FROM TEILNEHMER WHERE BUCHUNG_ID =" & Recordset("buchung_id") & "and STATUS = 2 and DAILYPLAN = 1" , Connection
         if not rsRaum.EOF then



         do while not rsRaum.eof


                TeilnehmerNameExtern = rsRaum("NAME")
                TeilnehmerFirmaExtern = rsRaum("FIRMA")  

             rsRaum.movenext

          loop

         end if
  rsRaum.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you could have more than one teilnehmer you of course have to loop through that recordset. otherwise you will only get the first record

Comment: I edited my question. I tried to loop like in my updated Question but still get only the first record. What iam doing wrong?

Comment: @Paks how do you know you only get the first record? is rsRaum.recordcount = 1?

Comment: Yes i did a response.Write from recordcount, and it return 1. i dont know why

Comment: well i also do not know why because i do not know your database schema. but obviously your sql statements are the problem. it seems to me that buchun_id is a primary key? so that sql will always return only one record...

Comment: than you have no more teilnehmer with STATUS = 2 and DAILYPLAN = 1

Comment: i checked all before i did the Post here. There are 3 Teilnehmer with Status = 2 and Dailyplan = 1

Comment: write the sql out to the page so you can see what sqls are ececuted

Comment: The Output on Page = SELECT NAME, FIRMA FROM TEILNEHMER WHERE BUCHUNG_ID =4493and STATUS = 2 and DAILYPLAN = 1. So that seems correct. But i did again a recordcount and now it returns -1. What is that?